# Why terminal does not show other yargs command?

Tags: node.js, yargs

When i run command `node app.js --help` , terminal shows only add command meanwhile i have defined three commands and all of them works. And when i use `parse()` method instead of `argv` why i get 'Removing a note' printed 2 times ?

```
const yargs = require('yargs');


yargs.command({
    command:'add',
    describe:'Adds new note',
    handler:function(){
    console.log('Adding a note')
    }
}).argv;

yargs.command({
    command:'remove',
    describe:'Removes a note',
    handler:function(){
    console.log('Removing a note')
    }
 }).argv;

yargs.command({
    command:'list',
    describe:'Fetches a list of notes',
    handler:function(){
    console.log('Fetching a list')
    }
 }).argv;

Commands:
  app.js add  Adds new note

Options:
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
 PS C:\Users\Sanket\Documents\node js\notes-app> 

PS C:\Users\Sanket\Documents\node js\notes-app> node app.js add   

Adding a note
PS C:\Users\Sanket\Documents\node js\notes-app> node app.js remove
Removing a note
Removing a note
PS C:\Users\Sanket\Documents\node js\notes-app> node app.js list  
Fetching a list
PS C:\Users\Sanket\Documents\node js\notes-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.argv` which is stopping the process before the others can be defined before `help` is invoked.

Remove `.argv` from all but the last command definition you create is the simplest fix for this.

```
const yargs = require('yargs');


yargs.command({
    command:'add',
    describe:'Adds new note',
    handler:function(){
    console.log('Adding a note')
    }
});

yargs.command({
    command:'remove',
    describe:'Removes a note',
    handler:function(){
    console.log('Removing a note')
    }
 });

yargs.command({
    command:'list',
    describe:'Fetches a list of notes',
    handler:function(){
    console.log('Fetching a list')
    }
 }).argv;
```

Comment: That worked ,thank you so much. But what does `argv` does?